# Пересортировка ORM Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, orm

Мне нужны скажем 30 самых популярных записей из таблицы.

```
$results = ORM::factory('Table')->order_by('rate', 'DESC')->limit(30)->find_all();
```

Но я хочу их вывести с сортировкой по полю 'name'. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = DB::select()->from(ORM::factory('Table')->table_name())->order_by('rate','DESC')->limit(30)->execute()->as_array();
usort($results, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

можно попробовать с орм, не знаю прокатит ли

```
$results = ORM::factory('Table')->order_by('rate', 'DESC')->limit(30)->find_all()->as_array();
usort($results, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = ORM::factory('Table')->order_by(array('rate','name'), 'DESC')->limit(30)->find_all();
```

В первый параметр order_by() передаем массив с полями для сортировки.

Comment: нет, сортирует не так, как надо. Хоть так array('rate','name'), хоть так array('name','rate'), в указанном Вами варианте ответа происходит сортировка по одному полю, а по второму полю происходит сортировка только если значения в полях совпали. Мне же нужно отсортировать только 30 полученных записей по имени (уже без учета рейтинга). Где-то находил, что надо создавать временную таблицу для результатов, но не знаю, может ли это ORM.